# How can I make an automatic copy of a MySQL database to another MySQL database on the same server?

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I have two MySQL databases called LIVE and REPORTS on the same server.

I want to copy the LIVE database and all its contents into the REPORTS database everyday at a specific time frame between 1 am and 5 am.

How could I do this automatically?

Comment: Why not replicate to a reports machine - unless you have the dbs on different disks?

Answer (score 1):

You can [setup second mysql instance with replication](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/setting-up-second-mysql-instance-replication-on-linux-in-10-steps). If you need to "copy" only during certain time period, you may choose to cron a script which will start and stop replication according to the time.
Again you can only choose to replicate-do-db certain databases as well.

Answer (score 1):

The following command should do the trick:

```
mysqldump --create-options --complete-insert -u *username* -p*password* LIVE > mysql -u *username* -p*password* REPORTS
```

If you are using Linux, you can add a line to /etc/crontab as follows:

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
  * 1  *   *   *  root  mysqldump --create-options --complete-insert -u *username* -p*password* LIVE > mysql -u *username* -p*password* REPORTS
```